# density and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

How to use the fact that $f:E\to F$ is an homeomorphism, if $cl(A)=E$ then $ cl(f(A)) =F $

I know that f is continuous then $f(cl(A))\subset cl(f(A))$ but how to continue? and where is used the fact that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You already say that you know that $f(cl(A)) \subset cl(f(A))$.

Presumably you also know the more general and abstract fact: for any continuous $g : X \to Y$ and any subset $W \subset X$ we have $g(cl(W)) \subset cl(g(W))$.

Now apply this fact using $g=f^{-1}$ and some useful choice of $W$.

Comment: I don't understand the second assumption

Comment: Which one is the second one?

Comment: about the function g

Comment: I simply generalized and abstracted what you said you knew, by replacing $f$ with $g$, replacing $E$ with $X$, repalacing $F$ with $Y$, and replacing $A$ with $W$.

Comment: but you use $f^{-1}$ how?

Comment: what you do with $  f^{-1}(cl(A))\subset  cl(f^{-1} (A))$ @Lee Mosher

Comment: You've chosen the wrong $W$. The expression $f^{-1}(cl(A))$ does not make any sense, because $cl(A)$ is a subset of $X$, but the variable $W$ in the expression $f^{-1}(W)$ must represent a subset of $Y$.

Comment: we chose W= f(A) @Lee Mosher

Comment: That should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple from definitions: $A \subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ iff $f[A]$ is dense in $Y$.

A set is dense iff it intersects every non-empty open set. If $A$ is dense and $O \subseteq Y$ is open and non-empty, $f[A] \cap O \neq \emptyset$ iff $A \cap f^{-1}[O] \neq \emptyset$ and the latter holds by continuity of $f$ and denseness of $A$ (and $f$ being a bijection too). And if $f[A]$ is dense and $O$ is non-empty open in $X$, $f[O]$ is nonempty open in $Y$ so intersects $f[A]$ and the preimage of the intersection point shows that $A$ intersects $O$ etc. This uses that $f$ is an open map.

$A$ dense implies $f[A]$ dense for any continuous and onto $f$. To go back we need $f$ to be open e.g., as we have here.